# Flutter | How do i get the last widget instance name?

Tags: flutter, dart

Let's say I'm having E-com app, I'm on Home page, I clicked on product and I jump on product details Widget page. this is a first scenario.
now I'm on cart Widget page, I click on product there, and I jump on Product's details Widget page.
now come to the need, once I come on Product's detail Widget page, there I want to get the last widget page name. How do I get that?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: AppTheme.of(context).secondaryBackground,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        leading: InkWell(
          onTap: () async {
                }),
),
),
})
```

in the above code, once I'll click on Back arrow (basically on InkWell), onTap, there  I want to check the last widget instance, which was the last widget instance?, how do i get that?

Comment: Please correct me, all you want is to know the page(widget) user moved to product details page (either from cart or home screen), is that correct..?

Comment: Active Widget instance tree, where I could get on what Widget I was previously?

Comment: yes pratik you are right